# Can I reference class attribute of sub-class in instance method?

Tags: typescript

I have a superclass `A` that has a class attribute `templateUrl`
and an instance method `f` that makes use of the class attribute:

```
class A {
    public static templateUrl: string = "default.html";
    public f() {
        console.log(A.templateUrl);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to say `self` instead of `A` in the body of `f` so
that sub-classes will access the overwritten templateUrl?

To be more specific, when I extend this class to a range of
specific classes...

```
class B extends A {
}

class C extends A {
    public static templateUrl: string = "projectX.html";
}
```

...  and then go:

```
new A().f()
new B().f()
new C().f()
```

...  I will see this:

```
default.html
default.html
default.html
```

...  but want to see this instead:

```
default.html
default.html
projectX.html
```

Is there a way?  Or am I just using the entirely wrong pattern?

Comment: Clearly, then, your `templateUrl` should be an instance property not a static property.

Comment: not so clearly :).  see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the nature of `constructor`s in JavaScript, you could do something like below which would avoid needing to store the value within each instance of your objects:

```
class A {
    public static templateUrl = "default.html";
    public f() {
        /* 
         the static value is stored on the constructor
         for the class, so we can grab it by 
         casting away the specific type and
         accessing the property directly
         */
        return (<any>this).constructor.templateUrl;
    }
}

class B extends A { }

class C extends A {
    public static templateUrl = "projectX.html";    
}

console.log(new A().f()); // <==default.html 
console.log(new B().f()); // <==default.html
console.log(new C().f()); // <==projectX.html
```

The constructor may be accessed via the `constructor` property of an object (or the `this` context). From there, you can access any properties that were stored as a `static`. `static` properties are automatically copied to derived classes via the code that is emitted by the TypeScript compiler.

The assertion of `<any>` is necessary to force the compiler to ignore the JavaScript syntax that is used to retrieve the property value.

Comment: neat!  now assume that the type of templateUrl changes (say it's an object and there are new attributes in a sub-class).  it would be great to get something like `typeof (<any>this).constructor.tmeplateUrl` (the typescript `typeof`, not the dynamic one), but I guess that won't work because the concrete type of this.constructor is only known at run time?

Comment: You could grab whatever is stored there and do a type assertion or use `instanceof` to check what has been stored before operating upon it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if every instance of the subclasses would like to redefine the value of `templateUrl` it is evident that what you want is an *instance field member* and *not a static field member* as you currently have.

So, the simplest solution could be:

```
class A {

    constructor(public templateUrl="default.html"){
    }

    public f() {
        console.log(this.templateUrl);
    }
}

class B extends A {}

class C extends A {
    constructor(){
        super("projectX.html");
    }
}


new A().f();
new B().f();
new C().f();
```

Which yields what you want:

```
default.html
default.html
projectX.html
```

**--Edit--**

About your comments on sharing the same value for a field

```
var url = 'index.html'
var a = new A(url);
var b = new B(url);
var c = new B(url);
```

Aren't they all sharing the same value?

Comment: while that does work for this example, it is only sometimes what you want.  if you want to change an attribute for two different instances of the same sub-class, then you want it to be an instance attribute.  but i want templateUrl to be the same for every instance of the same sub-class, so i like the answer by WiredPrairie much better.

Comment: @user2645074 I would say the problem with your original question is that you asked what you thought was the answer to your problem (how to use static field in subclases) instead of asking about the true problem (how to share state between instances of a subclass). From a software design standpoint your field must be an instance field. And I don't understand your comments, with my design all your subclasses can still share the same URL instance. You can see my edit where I prove the point. I think you just need to understand better the concepts of inheritance and object composition.

Comment: the difference between instance variables and class variables is very simple, and there are obvious applications for both (otherwise there wouldn't be any class variables): class variables share the same value over all instances, and instance variables don't.  i don't understand why you insist on talking about instance variables since my question is clearly about class variables.  and i don't see any need for being insulting either.